# Change the latex math font style in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

How can I change the math font style in matplotlib when using latex. For example, I have

```
matplotlib_font$_{latex_font}$
```

where the matplotlib_font shows up as the font set in my rc file, and Latex_font is in computer modern. I don't want all of my fonts to run off Latex, ie. I want to keep the rc file as

```
text.usetex         : False
```

But I need my latex font to match my matplotlib font.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Figured it out, in the rc (matplotlibrc) file set

```
mathtext.fontset : custom
```

Then update the math texts with the fonts that are needed in math mode

```
mathtext.rm  : Times New Roman
mathtext.it  : Times New Roman:italic
mathtext.bf  : Times New Roman:bold
```

Comment: I removed `mathtext.tt  : Times New Roman` because I do not believe this is needed as it is not used by LaTex.